# libcrypt.a undefined reference to NSSLOW_

Tags: linux, centos6, openssl

We have centos6 6.5 64bit server.  It had been setup for 32bit development.  Our project is statically linked.  A team member installed the most recent openssl, openssl-devel, and openssl-static 64bit and 32bit i686 libraries.  Nothing else in our setup has been modified.  Now when compiling we get a list of errors similar to

```
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): In function `__md5_crypt_r':
    (.text+0x99): undefined reference to `NSSLOW_Init'
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): In function `__md5_crypt_r':
    (.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `NSSLOWHASH_NewContext'
```

we have tried reverting out openssl packages but the error persists
thank you

Answer (score 0):

apparently libcrypt.a was replaced somewhere in the process.  We had to custom build using some help from

http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.distributions.gobo.general/month=20100601

configuring with

configure --prefix=glibc-2.12-1.47. el6_2.9.src/glibc-2.12-2-gc4ccff1/binary --host=i686-redhat-linux --build=i686-redhat-linux --enable-static --disable-nss-crypt CC='gcc -Wa,--32 -m32' CXX='g++ -Wa,--32 -m32' CFLAGS='-O2 -march=i686' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -march=i686' LDFLAGS=-m32